# JavaScript good practices: remove inline onsubmit(), global variables

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning good practices with JavaScript (btw, if you have articles about it to recommend me, I'll be grateful :D) and I have some questions about:

1. `onsubmit()`, `onclick()` and other *inline functions*
2. What should I do when the variable is `global`
3. `open()` method

### About 1 and 2

I have a form in my HTML page and I was using this way:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="myFunction();">
```

Inline JS is a bad practice and I must remove it. So, I removed `onsubmit="myFunction();"` and add in my JS (in a external file):

```
var form = document.myForm;

form.onsubmit = function myFunction() { /* codes hidden here */ };
```

But...

**1.** Why my code is not working? I have to use `window.onload` before? Sometimes I don't know when I should use it.

**2.** Once I read that I should not declare global variables (like `form` above). How can I make a local variable in that case then?

### About 3

**3.** In a function I generate a URL and the user clicks on a button to open it. But I read that `open()` is a **bad practice**. Is this true? If yes, how to replace?

Comment: for 1,how you defined it not working. if click the submit button, likely the page will refresh, and every change will be gone.for 2 and use var to make a local variable

Comment: Whenever someone says something is "bad practice", always ask them why. Inline listeners arn't inherrently "bad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the statement:

```
var form = document.myForm;
```

is evaluated, the form must exist in the DOM, otherwise `form` will be undefined. If the above is in the head, then when the code is executed and the assignment made the form almost certainly wont exist yet.

Any values that are dependent on DOM elements should be assigned after the DOM has loaded. The simplest way to ensure that is to place scripts immediately before the closing *body* tag.

There are other methods that load scripts on the DOMReady event (or similar) or wait for the window's *load* event, but that can cause a delay between when elements are visible and the script runs.

```
form.onsubmit = function myFunction() { /* codes hidden here */ };
```

If *form* is undefined you're in trouble… :-(

It is also a good idea to give global variables names that are unlikely to clash with standard globals (there are quite a lot of them, e.g. many browsers make all element names and IDs into global variables referencing the element to be compatible with ancient IE code), so better to do something like:

```
var formElement = document.forms['myForm'];
```

or better yet, keep your global variable count as low as is reasonable (zero is possible but not always sensible). e.g. you could do:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var form = document.myForm;
  form.onsubmit = function myFunction() { /* codes hidden here */ };
}
```

in code that is in the head. Or something like Kyle Weller's answer close to the closing body tag instead.

Answer (score 1):

window.onload makes sure that all content is loaded and ready on your page. One way you can limit the scope of your variables is by using a self-executing anonymous function like this:

```
(function(){
  var form = document.myForm;
  form.onsubmit = function myFunction() { /* codes hidden here */ };
})();
```

For number 3 you want a user to navigate to a certain url? You can use an  tag with these attributes:

```
<a href="http://www.myurl.com" target="_blank">Click on my url</a>
```

`target=_blank` makes the url open in a new tab or window if the user has their browser setup that way.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could use event listeners, like this:

   ```
   var form = document.getElementById("form");
   form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('form has been submitted!');
   });
   ```

   And, of course watch out for variables, which have been assigned DOM elements when they haven't been loaded yet (like RobG noted).
2. You should declare a main object like `app`, then add everything you need as it's properties or functions:

   ```
   var app = {};
   app.formElement = document.getElementById("form");
   app.submitButton = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
   app.someFunction = function(number){ return number};
   ```

   Bear in mind that you can also add objects into that object, for further categorization.
3. `.open()` method is considered bad practice, in terms of UX, because it simply opens a pop-up.

Comment: Is `e.preventDefault();` necessary?